# How to set particular spacing between first two lines?

Tags: spacing, formatting, line-spacing

I have this code

```
\textbf{An example of description:}

\begin{description}
\item[enumerate] let you create enumerated lists.
\item[itemize] let you create something
\item[description] let you create something else
\end{description}
```

All the lines have the same spacing between them.

I would like a bigger spacing line between \textbf{An example of description:} and \item[enumerate] let you create enumerated lists.

I tried

```
{\setstretch{2.0}
\textbf{An example of description:}

\begin{description}
\item[enumerate] let you create enumerated lists.}
\item[itemize] let you create something
\item[description] let you create something else
\end{description}
```

and the display is now 2.0 spacing in the whole code, not just the first and second line. Also marks an error strike but still compiles.

How can I indicate that only 2.0 spacing in the first two lines?

Comment: Hi @user459663, have you tried inserting a vertical space `\vspace`, e.g. `\vspace{10mm}` where you would like to have the additional vertical space?

Comment: Hi. No, I haven't tried, actually I think I need an horizontal space instead of vertical line.

Comment: @chrisma A space line between this lines \textbf{An example of description:} and \item[enumerate] let you create enumerated lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but let me take a guess:

Your original code (without the `\setstretch`) produces the following output:

[image]

Additional vertical spacing between the bold text and the start of the `\description` environment can be added using `\vspace`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\textbf{An example of description:}

\vspace{3em} %Can be mm, cm etc

\begin{description}
\item[enumerate] let you create enumerated lists.
\item[itemize] let you create something
\item[description] let you create something else
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Does this answer your question?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I wanted, thank you!

Comment: Perfect! You can accept the answer using the checkmark on the left side, to indicate that your question was answered :)